# How to start a function outside the function you are working in

Tags: java, listener

I am still new to Java and i would like to know how i can achieve this scenario. I have a function that performs certain calculations and after it is done i would like to pass the result to another function so that it can send a notification.

My problem is that the second function seems to cause the program to wait for a response eventhough its a void function. As a result my program takes time to return the result becuase it is performing another task which should be independent.

Here is some sudo code to exaplain what i am trying to do :

```
public class MyCalculationclass {

     public String PerformCalculations (Object object){
       // perform calculation
       sendNotificationToUser(usernotificationToken, calculationValue)

       return "Success"

        }

     public void sendNotificationToUser(String usernotificationToken,String calculationValue ){

          // send user the notification
       }

}
```

I would like to notify the void function to run when my calculations are complete in such a manner that i do not have to wait for the void function to run before i get the Success message. How can i achieve this in java.

Comment: Use Threads. `new Thread(() -> sendNotificationToUser(usernotificationToken, calculationValue)).start()`.

Comment: must familiase with backgroud of Java. Java has not functions but methods. Seems parts of Your question assume Thread usage, read what it is

Comment: good idea thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make proper use of threads, you should consider creating an [executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
public class MyCalculationclass {
     private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

     public String PerformCalculations (Object object){
       // perform calculation
       executorService.execute(() ->
           sendNotificationToUser(usernotificationToken, calculationValue));

       return "Success"

        }

     public void sendNotificationToUser(String usernotificationToken,String calculationValue ){

          // send user the notification
       }

}
```

Later on, you may want to replace `execute()` with `submit()` to get a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object. Or even better, use a [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-java.util.concurrent.Executor-).

Comment: The "perform calculation" part should be within the lambda because that's what needs to be parallelized.

Comment: @daniu That's not how I read this phrase: "I would like to notify the void function **to run when my calculations are complete** in such a manner that i do not have to wait for the void function to run before i get the Success message." (emphasis mine)

Comment: You're right, he does state that the "problem is that the _second_ function seems to cause the program to wait", I missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

Use Threads:

```
new Thread(() -> sendNotificationToUser(usernotificationToken, calculationValue)).start();
```

instead

```
sendNotificationToUser(usernotificationToken, calculationValue);
```

Comment: Are there any effects of performing an expensive operation/calculation on a thread